# Using arraylist in decision tables

Tags: ibm-odm

IBM ODM

I was working on a decision table which has to add the elements in columns to an array list in action column.

I have some an attribute with several names. I would like to add some of those names to an array list so that I can exclude them from executing for particular rule.

If anyone has other options apart from using decision table that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a variable in the Variable List which is a type of Array. Then, I created a decision table which checks the rule name and then adds "String"(Object Name) to the Array. Now, we are all set to exclude that particular String/Object for some particular Rules. In the definition part of your rule, Check "where this xxx is not one of Array". It can be useful when you have a lot of Strings/Objects to exclude from Execution.